# cmake set path when reading files

Tags: c++, makefile, path, cmake, g++

My folder structure is

```
├── build
│   ├── ..
│   └── Makefile
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── test.hpp
└── yuefei3.jpg
```

In the main file, I use relative path to read an image:

```
 cv::Mat img = cv::imread("./yuefei3.jpg");
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6) 
project(main) 

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) 
add_executable(main main.cpp) 

target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

However, because the executable file is executed from `build`, it cannot read the image in the relative path.

How can I set the relative path to something so that the executable file can read the image? (I don't want to use absolute path)

Comment: Use  `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("../yuefei3.jpg");`

Comment: Are there any way not to use this? Because if I change structure of the folders, I have to change the path of this file. It seems to be inconvenient.

Comment: I am looking for a way in `cmake`.

Comment: I don't think its possible. CMake has little to do with the execution of your application. I mean `CMake` can copy the image to the same folder as the executable or create a shell script to run your application from the folder containing the image but not sure you would want either of these.

Comment: I think I would prefer the solution creating a shell script to run the application from the folder containing the image. I am new to `cmake` so it's quite hard to understand the structure. At first I thought `cmake` was the same as `webpack` (in some ways) but it turned out they were different.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want... You have **two** trees: *source* tree, which contains the image file, and *binary* tree, which contains the executable. *In general*, these trees can have any relative location. So, for refer image file from executable, you need to **explicitely** tell the executable about source tree location. This could be done either at configuration stage (by creating a macro with this location and using this macro in the source file), or at runtime (e.g. via script). CMake may help you in the first approach, but second one is fully up to you. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: You could just use and pass command line argument for the directory of the file. But that has nothing to do with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this in the opposite way, by copying artifacts needed at run time into the build directory.  Maybe that's an option for your as well.

Comment: You could easily do that automatically with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} to get the path.